# Change text color or display it on top of the path so the path won't cover it

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I am new to D3js and I have some sort of bug here. When the percentage of data is very low, the path will appear shorter too, logically. But that also "hides" my text which displays the data percentage. Is there any way possible to make my text white or at least make it appear on top of it's path?
Here's my code snipped. Thank you in advance

```js
    var data = [
        {"platform": "Yes", "percentage": 87.00}, //skyblue
        {"platform": "No", "percentage": 1.00},    //darkblue
        {"platform": "N/A", "percentage": 17.00} //orange
    ];
    
    var svgWidth = 200, svgHeight = 200, radius =  Math.min(svgWidth, svgHeight) / 2;
    var svg = d3.select('svg')
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight);
    
    //Create group element to hold pie chart    
    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")") ;
    
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
    
    var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) { 
         return d.percentage; 
    });
    
    var path = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(80)
        .innerRadius(40);
     
    var arc = g.selectAll("arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter()
        .append("g");
    
    arc.append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.percentage); });
            
    var label = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(20)
        .innerRadius(100);
                
    arc.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; 
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return +d.data.percentage+"%"; });
```

```css
            .cnt-main-container
            {
                display:flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            .charts{
                display:flex;
                justify-content: center;
                flex-direction: row;
                flex-wrap: nowrap;
            }
            .info{
                display:flex;
                justify-content: center;
                flex-direction: row;
            }

            #dot1{
                width:10px;
                height:10px;
                background:rgb(39, 81, 194);
                display:inline-block;
            }
            label{
                margin-left:3px;
                margin-top:-3px;
                margin-right:5px;
            }
            #dot2{
                width:10px;
                height:10px;
                background:rgb(233, 106, 3);
                display:inline-block;
            }

            #dot3{
                background-color:skyblue;
                width:10px;
                height:10px;
                display:inline-block;
            }
```

```html
        <div class="cnt-main-container">
            <div class="charts">
                <svg class="pie-chart"></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <div id="dot1"></div>
                <label for="dot1">Yes</label>
                <div id="dot2"></div>
                <label for="dot2">No</label>
                <div id="dot3"></div>
                <label for="dot3">N/A</label>
            </div>
    </div>
    
            <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a SVG the order of the elements defines the painting order. Thus, the simples solution is sorting your enter selection i such a way that small slices will be on the top:

```
.sort((a, b) => b.data.percentage - a.data.percentage);
```

Also, you can set a small white stroke to the texts, if the browser supports `paint-order`.

Here is the result:

```js
var data = [{
    "platform": "Yes",
    "percentage": 87.00
  }, //skyblue
  {
    "platform": "No",
    "percentage": 1.00
  }, //darkblue
  {
    "platform": "N/A",
    "percentage": 17.00
  } //orange
];

var svgWidth = 200,
  svgHeight = 200,
  radius = Math.min(svgWidth, svgHeight) / 2;
var svg = d3.select('svg')
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight);

//Create group element to hold pie chart    
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d.percentage;
});

var path = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(80)
  .innerRadius(40);

var arc = g.selectAll("arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .sort((a, b) => b.data.percentage - a.data.percentage);

arc.append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.percentage);
  });

var label = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(20)
  .innerRadius(100);

arc.append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return +d.data.percentage + "%";
  });
```

```css
.cnt-main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.charts {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#dot1 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgb(39, 81, 194);
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#dot2 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgb(233, 106, 3);
  display: inline-block;
}

#dot3 {
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

text {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  paint-order: stroke;
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt-main-container">
  <div class="charts">
    <svg class="pie-chart"></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div id="dot1"></div>
    <label for="dot1">Yes</label>
    <div id="dot2"></div>
    <label for="dot2">No</label>
    <div id="dot3"></div>
    <label for="dot3">N/A</label>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much, much appreciated.

Comment: Can I also ask you one more question I am dealing with ? It's about versions of D3, I have two different charts on my website and one is made with D3 v3 and the other one is made with D3 v4 and having them together in one site deletes one another because I have to declare that I am using both version on my meta data header and since I am all new to D3 it's a big problem for me and it's already causing headaches haha. Will you help me find a solution for this pls?

Comment: @Leo the best solution is refactoring the v3 chart to v4. Don't try "jury-rigging" fixes to keep two D3 versions in the same page.

Comment: In that case, I want to keep the newest version, which is d3 v7, but if I do that, many bugs will pop up because of the syntax gets changed a lot during these version updates and many functions either change their entire name or they combine somehow and now I can't really use the same code I have written with d3 v3 in another site running d3 v4/v7 code. What about this scenario?

Comment: Same thing: refactor the codes for using the same D3 version.